# How do I build a read/write 4-nibble RAM memory system using flip flops?

Tags: computer-architecture, circuits, memory-hardware, memory-access

Currently, I'm learning about flip flops and how it is used in RAM to store memory so I'm trying to recreate the circuitry in Logisim.  I know the components I need which are address register, 4-bit data register, 1 bit read/write register and the actual 4 nibble RAM with its own address space and data space.  How do I create each individual pieces and put them together?

Comment: This may be better for [electronics.SE]. Community votes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put multiplexers and selector/decoders around your flipflops.

The read path needs to multiplex each nibble using the 2 address line.

The write path is selecting with these two address lines with nibble should be modified.